# Connected to Wifi, but no ping to router - Netgear AC6100 driver: 8812au

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 with updates via Ethernet. Now I want to use my Wifi at home.
I have a Netgear AC6100 (Wifi USB stick) and found a driver for the stick on [Github](https://github.com/gnab/rtl8812au). I compliled it and load it automatically at boot.
The problem is, that I cannot reach anything in the network.

```
# ping 192.168.1.1
PING 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- 192.168.1.1 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 3023ms
```

As you can see the driver is working (otherwise I couldn't make an `iwlist scan`) and the router gives me a correct IP address via DHCP.

My ideas to fix the problem are gone. :-(

Do you have any ideas?

TIA

Kai aka Cyoux

ifconfig

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr e0:cb:4e:1b:b7:2b  
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:373 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:373 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:26157 (26.1 KB)  TX bytes:26157 (26.1 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 04:a1:51:89:44:ba  
      inet addr:192.168.1.44  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::6a1:51ff:fe89:44ba/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:27 errors:0 dropped:29 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:74 errors:0 dropped:2 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:5149 (5.1 KB)  TX bytes:15954 (15.9 KB)`
```

iwconfig

```
wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"kairokai"  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"
      Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.432 GHz  Access Point: 84:9C:A6:30:A0:EA   
      Bit Rate:150 Mb/s   Sensitivity:0/0  
      Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Encryption key:****-****-****-****-****-****-****-****   Security mode:open
      Power Management:off
      Link Quality=100/100  Signal level=100/100  Noise level=0/100
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

ip addr

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default 
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
link/ether e0:cb:4e:1b:b7:2b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether 04:a1:51:89:44:ba brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 192.168.1.44/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global wlan0
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 fe80::6a1:51ff:fe89:44ba/64 scope link 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

route

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0 
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0
```

nm-tool

```
NetworkManager Tool


State: connected (global)


- Device: wlan0  [kairokai] ----------------------------------------------------

  Type:              802.11 WiFi

  Driver:            rtl8812au

  State:             connected

  Default:           yes

  HW Address:        04:A1:51:89:44:BA


  Capabilities:
Speed:           150 Mb/s


  Wireless Properties
WEP Encryption:  yes
WPA Encryption:  yes
WPA2 Encryption: yes


  Wireless Access Points (* = current AP)
WLAN-B65605:     Infra, 1C:C6:3C:B6:56:14, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 87 WPA2
HITRON-42F0:     Infra, 78:8D:F7:2E:42:F8, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 87 WPA WPA2
FRITZ!Box 7362 SL: Infra, 34:81:C4:10:90:E2, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 65 WPA2
ImPalast:        Infra, 00:1C:28:74:EE:B7, Freq 2452 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 65 WPA2
WLAN-7EE193:     Infra, 84:9C:A6:7E:E1:9A, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 62 WPA2
KD WLAN Hotspot+:Infra, 78:8D:F7:2E:42:FA, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 85
*kairokai:       Infra, 84:9C:A6:30:A0:EA, Freq 2432 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 75 WPA2


  IPv4 Settings:
Address:         192.168.1.44
Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
Gateway:         192.168.1.1

DNS:             192.168.1.1



- Device: eth0 -----------------------------------------------------------------

  Type:              Wired

  Driver:            r8169

  State:             unavailable

  Default:           no

  HW Address:        E0:CB:4E:1B:B7:2B


  Capabilities:
Carrier Detect:  yes


  Wired Properties
Carrier:         off
```

[7] iwlist scan

```
wlan0     Scan completed :
      Cell 01 - Address: 84:9C:A6:30:A0:EA
                ESSID:"kairokai"
                Protocol:IEEE 802.11bgn
                Mode:Master
                Frequency:2.432 GHz (Channel 5)
                Encryption key:on
                Bit Rates:300 Mb/s
                Extra:rsn_ie=30140100000fac040100000fac040100000fac020100
                IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                    Group Cipher : CCMP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                   Preauthentication Supported
                IE: Unknown: DD8D0050F204104A00011010440001021041000100103B0001031047001000000000000000030000849CA630A0E9102100066F3220426F781023000941525637353244505710240007312E30312E32351042000A323132333031303538321054000800060050F20400011011001B6F3220426F7820576972656C65737320526F757465722857464129100800020084
                Quality=100/100  Signal level=100/100  
      Cell 02 - Address: 1C:C6:3C:B6:56:14
                ESSID:"WLAN-B65605"
                Protocol:IEEE 802.11bgn
                Mode:Master
                Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                Encryption key:on
                Bit Rates:144 Mb/s
                Extra:rsn_ie=30140100000fac040100000fac040100000fac020000
                IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                    Group Cipher : CCMP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                IE: Unknown: DD910050F204104A00011010440001021041000100103B00010310470010000000000000000300001CC63CB656141021000B436F72706F726174696F6E10230009564756383533394A5710240008312E33362E3030301042000A4A3232383130333833351054000800060050F204000110110014576972656C65737320526F757465722857464129100800020084103C000103
                Quality=0/100  Signal level=91/100  
      Cell 03 - Address: 34:81:C4:10:90:E2
                ESSID:"FRITZ!Box 7362 SL"
                Protocol:IEEE 802.11bgn
                Mode:Master
                Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                Encryption key:on
                Bit Rates:300 Mb/s
                Extra:rsn_ie=30140100000fac040100000fac040100000fac020000
                IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                    Group Cipher : CCMP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                IE: Unknown: DD6F0050F204104A0001101044000102103B000103104700100A5D2E2BA8926879A52D3481C41090E21021000341564D1023000446426F78102400043030303010420004303030301054000800060050F20400011011000446426F78100800022788103C0001031049000600372A000120
                Quality=0/100  Signal level=68/100  
      Cell 04 - Address: 00:1C:28:74:EE:B7
                ESSID:"ImPalast"
                Protocol:IEEE 802.11bg
                Mode:Master
                Frequency:2.452 GHz (Channel 9)
                Encryption key:on
                Bit Rates:54 Mb/s
                Extra:rsn_ie=30140100000fac040100000fac040100000fac020000
                IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                    Group Cipher : CCMP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                IE: Unknown: DD310050F204104A0001101044000102104700102880288028801880A880001C2874EEB7103C0001011049000600372A000120
                Quality=0/100  Signal level=62/100  
      Cell 05 - Address: 78:8D:F7:2E:42:F8
                ESSID:"HITRON-42F0"
                Protocol:IEEE 802.11bgn
                Mode:Master
                Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                Encryption key:on
                Bit Rates:300 Mb/s
                Extra:wpa_ie=dd160050f20101000050f20401000050f20401000050f202
                IE: WPA Version 1
                    Group Cipher : CCMP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                Extra:rsn_ie=30140100000fac040100000fac040100000fac020000
                IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                    Group Cipher : CCMP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                IE: Unknown: DD9D0050F204104A0001101044000102103B000103104700102880288028801880A880788DF72E42F81021001852616C696E6B20546563686E6F6C6F67792C20436F72702E1023001C52616C696E6B20576972656C6573732041636365737320506F696E74102400065254323836301042000831323334353637381054000800060050F20400011011000952616C696E6B41505310080002210C103C000101
                Quality=0/100  Signal level=96/100  
      Cell 06 - Address: 78:8D:F7:2E:42:FA
                ESSID:"KD WLAN Hotspot+"
                Protocol:IEEE 802.11bgn
                Mode:Master
                Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                Encryption key:off
                Bit Rates:300 Mb/s
                Quality=0/100  Signal level=96/100  
      Cell 07 - Address: 88:E3:AB:9C:E7:DF
                ESSID:""
                Protocol:IEEE 802.11AC
                Mode:Master
                Frequency:5.5 GHz (Channel 100)
                Encryption key:on
                Bit Rates:867 Mb/s
                Extra:rsn_ie=30140100000fac040100000fac040100000fac020c00
                IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                    Group Cipher : CCMP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                IE: Unknown: DD310050F204104A00011010440001021047001000000000000000000000000000000000103C0001031049000600372A000120
                Quality=0/100  Signal level=26/100
```

[8] rfkill list

```
1: phy1: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

[9] lsmod

```
Module                  Size  Used by
nls_iso8859_1          12713  1 
usb_storage            62209  1 
bnep                   19624  2 
rfcomm                 69160  0 
bluetooth             391136  10 bnep,rfcomm
dm_crypt               23177  0 
8812au               1017700  0 
cfg80211              484040  1 8812au
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     46368  1 
snd_hda_codec_via      27860  1 
gpio_ich               13476  0 
snd_hda_intel          56451  5 
snd_hda_codec         192906  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_via,snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep              13602  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm               102099  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
snd_page_alloc         18710  2 snd_pcm,snd_hda_intel
snd_seq_midi           13324  0 
snd_seq_midi_event     14899  1 snd_seq_midi
coretemp               13435  0 
snd_rawmidi            30144  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                61560  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
kvm_intel             143187  0 
snd_seq_device         14497  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
kvm                   455835  1 kvm_intel
snd_timer              29482  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd                    69322  21     snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_via,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device,snd_seq_midi
serio_raw              13462  0 
i7core_edac            24122  0 
edac_core              62291  2 i7core_edac
lpc_ich                21080  0 
soundcore              12680  1 snd
asus_atk0110           18657  0 
mac_hid                13205  0 
parport_pc             32701  0 
ppdev                  17671  0 
lp                     17759  0 
parport                42348  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
pata_acpi              13038  0 
hid_generic            12548  0 
usbhid                 52659  0 
hid                   106148  2 hid_generic,usbhid
radeon               1522640  3 
psmouse               106714  0 
i2c_algo_bit           13413  1 radeon
ttm                    85150  1 radeon
drm_kms_helper         55071  1 radeon
ahci                   25819  1 
r8169                  67581  0 
firewire_ohci          40409  0 
mii                    13934  1 r8169
drm                   303102  5 ttm,drm_kms_helper,radeon
firewire_core          68769  1 firewire_ohci
crc_itu_t              12707  1 firewire_core
libahci                32716  1 ahci
pata_jmicron           12758  0
```

[10] lsusb -v (relevant parts)

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 413c:3012 Dell Computer Corp. Optical Wheel Mouse
(...)
Device Status:     0x0000
  (Bus Powered)

Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Device Status:     0x0001
  Self Powered

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
(...)
Device Status:     0x0001
  Self Powered

Bus 001 Device 006: ID 1e3d:2093 Chipsbank Microelectronics Co., Ltd CBM209x Flash Drive (OEM)
(...)
Device Status:     0x0000
  (Bus Powered)

Bus 001 Device 004: ID 413c:2003 Dell Computer Corp. Keyboard
(...)
Device Status:     0x0000
  (Bus Powered)

Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0846:9052 NetGear, Inc. 
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.10
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x0846 NetGear, Inc.
  idProduct          0x9052 
  bcdDevice            2.00
  iManufacturer           1 Realtek 
  iProduct                2 802.11ac WLAN Adapter 
  iSerial                 3 00e04c000001
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           60
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xe0
      Self Powered
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower              500mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           6
      bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
      bInterfaceSubClass    255 Vendor Specific Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol    255 Vendor Specific Protocol
      iInterface              2 802.11ac WLAN Adapter 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x84  EP 4 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x05  EP 5 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x06  EP 6 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
    bInterval               0
  Endpoint Descriptor:
    bLength                 7
    bDescriptorType         5
    bEndpointAddress     0x87  EP 7 IN
    bmAttributes            3
      Transfer Type            Interrupt
      Synch Type               None
      Usage Type               Data
    wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
    bInterval               3
  Endpoint Descriptor:
    bLength                 7
    bDescriptorType         5
    bEndpointAddress     0x08  EP 8 OUT
    bmAttributes            2
      Transfer Type            Bulk
      Synch Type               None
      Usage Type               Data
    wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
    bInterval               0
  Endpoint Descriptor:
    bLength                 7
    bDescriptorType         5
    bEndpointAddress     0x09  EP 9 OUT
    bmAttributes            2
      Transfer Type            Bulk
      Synch Type               None
      Usage Type               Data
    wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
    bInterval               0
Binary Object Store Descriptor:
  bLength                 5
  bDescriptorType        15
  wTotalLength           12
  bNumDeviceCaps          1
  USB 2.0 Extension Device Capability:
    bLength                 7
    bDescriptorType        16
    bDevCapabilityType      2
    bmAttributes   0x00000002
      Link Power Management (LPM) Supported
Device Status:     0x0001
  Self Powered

Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
(...)
Device Status:     0x0001
  Self Powered

Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
(...)
Device Status:     0x0001
  Self Powered
```

Comment: You may want to add the output of `lsusb` for good order.

Comment: @mikewhatever Thanks for the hint. I added `lsusb -v`.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Based on your very thorough post, everything appears to be in order - yet it is not working. You may need to switch to a non free kernel module, rather than the bcmwl-kernel-source.</strike>

From terminal:

```
 sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
```

And then

```
 sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
```

When done, restart and let us know how it works.

Edit: I think (or thought) some Netgear used Broadcom chipset, but according to [wikidev](https://wikidevi.com/wiki/Netgear_A6100) your device uses Realtek RTL8811AU driver.

Okay here we go. The driver you downloaded from github was rtl8812au, but your driver should be   RTL8811AU. There is a link for the driver you need on wikidev

[Driver Link](http://www.edimax.com/images/Image/Driver_Utility/Wireless/NIC/EW-7822UAC/EW-7822UAC_linux_v4.2.2_7502.20130517.tar.gz)

Or if you prefer 
[github](https://github.com/abperiasamy/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux)

Comment: What? Why install a Broadcom driver, when there is no Broadcom card?

Comment: I was saying to purge the broadcom  (I think it there by default) and try the non-free

Comment: Ah, yes, my mistake. Anyway, I still don't think that's the way, because bcmwl is not installed by default. ...and do you know what's in linux-firmware-nonfree
 that is supposed to help the OP?

Comment: I was thinking it had some RTL drivers in there as I think some Netgear used Broadcom and some uses Realtek. Apparently it only has the bcms in there, so yeah not the right answer.

Comment: Updated answer with correct explanation and a link to the proper driver.

Comment: Thank you @geoffmcc!
I used the Edimax driver link - and it didn't compile (due to kernel incompatibility?).
I used the github driver link and it did compile, but the situation is the same:
nm-tool says connected, ifconfig and iwconfig look good, iwlist scan shows all the Wifis around, but when pinging the router there is no answer.

(Should this go into a comment or an answer?)

Comment: Have you tried to connect to WiFi elsewhere?

Comment: I use this Wifi stick on a PC. I have not yet put my PC to a friends house to try it there. 

I have used this stick on Windows with the same wifi at home. 

Does this answer your question?